# What is the risk of self-detonation or meltdown of unattended nuclear arsenal?

Tags: nuclear-physics, nuclear-engineering, explosions

Assume some missiles or bombs left unattended for at least 1,000 years. Chance of self-detonation? After playing with Powder Toy a bit, started me thinking: if Polonium and Americium are break-down products, with shorter half-lives, could they trigger a criticality? 100% they'd all have a meltdown yes?